# Percorrer todas as linhas de uma DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Tenho este for:

```
For Each DataGridViewRow In F_Principal.DataGridView2.Rows
```

Como faço para seleccionar fila a fila? Existe maneira de ver quantas vezes o for se repetiu?

Answer (score 3):

Consegui responder sozinho, mas deixo aqui a resposta de qualquer maneira para quem quiser.

```
For Each lel As DataGridViewRow In F_Principal.DataGridView2.Rows
       MsgBox("Index : " & lel.Index)
Next
```

A variável "lel" vai ser a linha actual, e podem tirar dai as infos que quiserem.